# button onclick button working weirdly

Tags: javascript

i am new in front end developing. i am currently working on ajax requests in javascript, trying to add TABLEs and OLs of an html page in another page. the coding is as follows ...

### main html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
       <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="AjaxRequestCreatingElements.js"></script>-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="ato">get all tables and ordered list's</button>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="AjaxRequestCreatingElements.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

### html page which is requested by XMLHttpRequest in javascript code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <table>
            <tr>
            <th>sr. no</th><th>topic</th><th>comment</th></tr>
                <tr><td>1</td><td>blah blah blah from div</td><td>i dont know</td></tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div>
            <ol>
                <li>blah blah blah..from div</li>
                <li>other blah blah blah....</li>
                <li>and an another blah blah blah....</li>
            </ol>
        </div>
        <table>
            <tr>
            <th>sr. no</th><th>topic</th><th>comment</th></tr>
                <tr><td>1</td><td>blah blah blah</td><td>i dont know</td></tr>
            </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

### javascript code making ajax request

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", "HtmlCopyFrom.html", true);
request.send(null);
var count = 0;
request.onreadystatechange = function ()
{
    if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200)
    {
        //alert("hi ");
        var newDoc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument("example");
        newDoc.documentElement.innerHTML = request.responseText;
        var tableElements = newDoc.getElementsByTagName('Table');
        var olElements = newDoc.getElementsByTagName('ol');
        document.getElementById("ato").onclick = function ()
        {
            //document.getElementById("ato").onclick = function ()
            for (var i = 0; i < tableElements.length; i++)
            {
                document.body.appendChild(tableElements[i]);
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < olElements.length; i++)
            {
                document.body.appendChild(olElements[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

****Problem****

i need to click 2 times to get all the table and ol elements for this page. i just want to click once and get all table and ol elements instead..

please help.

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Your code is weird. You request the data from the server (which is asynchronous) and just parse it via onclick event. Ye, if your request takes too long, you'll have to click 2 times.

try changing it like this:

```
document.getElementById("ato").onclick = function ()
{

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    request.open("GET", "HtmlCopyFrom.html", true); 
    request.send(null); var count = 0;     
    request.onreadystatechange = function () {

        if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200)
        {
            //alert("hi ");
            var newDoc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument("example");
            newDoc.documentElement.innerHTML = request.responseText;
            var tableElements = newDoc.getElementsByTagName('Table');
            var olElements = newDoc.getElementsByTagName('ol');

            //document.getElementById("ato").onclick = function ()
            for (var i = 0; i < tableElements.length; i++)
            {
                document.body.appendChild(tableElements[i]);
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < olElements.length; i++)
            {
                document.body.appendChild(olElements[i]);
            }

        }
    } 
}
```

this should work. (not testet your code)